# Nexus GraqphQL server does not restart

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

I'm running a `Graqphql` Server using `nexus` and `nexus-prisma-plugin`, `npx nexus dev` runs the server but takes a few seconds and the server does not restart on file changes. There is nothing provided in the documentation and I thought `nexus dev` was supposed to listen to file changes.

What am I missing, Or is there a different command?

I am running this on `WSL Ubuntu 20.04`

Comment: `nexus dev` should watch the filesystem and restart on file changes. What does your tsconfig.json look like?

Comment: @RyanJenkins Everything seems to be in place, I even have this plugin key 
`"plugins": [{ "name": "nexus/typescript-language-service" }],` I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/graphql-nexus/nexus/issues/1203) on the nexus repo, they said it was a bug, but haven't heard back in a while now after I commented my logs